# what Regex works for this?

Tags: php, regex

I would to grab whatever text is between "Nadal@gmail.com" and "This e-mail (and attachment(s)) is confidential, proprietary," but dont know what is the best and most reliable way to do this. I thought regex but perhaps someone knows better. the number of empty lines may increase or decrease but those 2 strings will always have text between them. In this case the text is "testttinggg"

```
---------- Forwarded message ---------- From: person name Date: 2011/12/1 Subject: RE: this is a test subject To: Nadal@gmail.com

    testingggggg

    This e-mail (and attachment(s)) is confidential, proprietary,
```

I tried to write

```
       preg_match('/nadal@gmail\.com(.*?)This e-mail \(and attachment\(s\)\) is confidential,/', $wholeBody, $matches);     echo $matches[1];
```

but it didnt work..

Comment: IS there a specific question in there or just "Can you do this for me"

Comment: What should happen if someone sends an email with the text `Hey Nadal@gmail.com, This e-mail (and attachment(s)) is confidential, proprietary, but I just wanted to say hi!`

Comment: it wont happen, this has more happening in the background but Ive written a regex and that didnt work... I tried 

           preg_match('/nadal@gmail\.com(.*?)This e-mail \(and attachment\(s\)\) is confidential,/', $wholeBody, $matches);     echo $matches[1];

Comment: possible duplicate of [what REGEX in php would I need for this?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8347423/what-regex-in-php-would-i-need-for-this)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're on the right way with your regex. You have to remember that the dot `.` does not include linebreaks by default so you have to add the `DOTALL` modifier.

You can try this. In capturegroup 1 you'll have the content (without the empty whitespaces and linebreaks)

```
(?<=Nadal@gmail.com)\s*(.*?)\s*(?=This e-mail \(and attachment\(s\)\) is confidential, proprietary,)
```

You can see it in action here: http://regexr.com?2vc19

**Update:**

```
preg_match('/(?<=Nadal@gmail.com)\s*(.*?)\s*(?=This e-mail \(and attachment\(s\)\) is confidential, proprietary,)/s', $message, $matches);
```

http://codepad.viper-7.com/C6Mxqd

Comment: Tried this aint working...
   preg_match('/(?<=nadal@gmail.com)\s*(.*?)\s*(?=This e-mail \(and attachment\(s\)\) is confidential, proprietary,)/',  $message, $matches);    
print_r($matches);

Comment: see my update. I've added the `s` modifier which includes linebreaks in the dot. And you've missed to copy the backslashes before the parentheses.

Comment: @Nadal what? Follow the link in at the bottom of my post. It works perfectly there.

Comment: I saw it there it works, why wont it work with what I have though? like it pulls out the message and all but it repeats sumthing, I can fix the repeat with str_replace though so its all good!